# Filter Control for Grid/TreeGrid

Tags: rally

Is the Filter Control component available for the Grid/TreeGrid (similar to the filter within the Portfolio Items dashboard)?  Per the SDK 2.0 documentation, it seems this component is only available for the GridBoard.

Answer (score 0):

`gridboard` is a wrapper around treegrid or board, and filtercontrol plugin should work with a TreeGrid. Here is an example of a tree grid with `enableHierarchy` set to true and a `rallygridboardcustomfiltercontrol` plugin:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.TreeStoreBuilder').build({
            models: ['userstory'],
            autoLoad: true,
            enableHierarchy: true
        }).then({
            success: this._onStoreBuilt,
            scope: this
        });
    },

    _onStoreBuilt: function(store) {
        var modelNames = ['userstory'];
        var context = this.getContext();
        this.add({
            xtype: 'rallygridboard',
            modelNames: modelNames,
            context:context,
            enableHierarchy: 'true',
            toggleState: 'grid',
            plugins: [
                {
                    ptype: 'rallygridboardcustomfiltercontrol',
                    filterControlConfig: {
                        modelNames: modelNames
                    }
                }
            ],
            cardBoardConfig: {
                attribute: 'ScheduleState'
            },
            gridConfig: {
                store: store,
                columnCfgs: [
                    'Name',
                    'ScheduleState',
                    'Owner',
                    'PlanEstimate'
                ]
            },
            height: this.getHeight()
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: the example seems to use the gridboard type.  do you have a similar example using the filter for grid/treegird?